# Linux redirecting a directory to some other directory only for a specific application

Tags: virtual-machine, symlink

I have run a program that accesses some files from the directory `/etc/somedir`. 
What I want to do is whenever it tries to access `/etc/somedir/somefile` it automatically redirects to `/home/arch/someoterdirectory/somefile`. Is this possible only for a specific application?.

Please note that I don't want to use symbolic links as I only want to do this for a specific program, rest of the programs can access `/etc/somedir` as it is.

Comment: This problem sounds very much like a [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Yes, that's possible in Linux with a mount namespace and a bind mount. Less reliably, and much messier, it could also be done with a `LD_PRELOAD` hack. But why not just modify that application in the first place? Even binary applications can have strings changed within them, provided that they're the same size or shorter.

Comment: Do you have control of the application (is it a script you can edit?) What kind of access is that (a file argument, reading some lib file hardcoded)? If you provide some more details, you could get an answer tailored to your needs.

Comment: Yes, I have the source code of the program. But the problem is that it is extremely big in size.

Comment: So, it's hard to identify into the code where are all the calls to `/etc/somedir/somefile` or to other files, but it is probably not difficult to identify where the directory `/etc/somedir` is configured to be a variable for the script, am I right?